# About Product Quantity drop down And add to cart button

Tags: multiple-add-to-cart

Hi I would like to have two **Add to cart** buttons which add specified quantities for my products and remove the input field i want quantity drop down instead of this.

=

I'd like

One for Order Sample button for which by default quantity select 1.
And other for bulk order for which quantiy start from 25,50,75,100,125....and so on.
Wondering on the best way to do this, I would also like to implement this on the product view page

Thanks

Comment: are you need two buttons 1 Add to cart & 2 Bulk order with single drop down and  it redirect to cart page right?

Comment: Yes.. Two Button 1 text With sample order for that by default quantity 1. and second with text Bulk order For that Quantity more than one But Like 25,50,75 like that and yes both button redirect to cart page.

Comment: are need to one input type & one drop down or need to single drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assist you with this but do you have any coding knowledge? Because if don't this will be very tricky for you to pull of!

And let me suggest this: instead of having two **Add to cart** buttons just have one and the dropdown by default is **1** so if the user wants to buy more selects one of the other values that you listed on the dropdown.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for reply.. Yes I have coding Knowledge.. I want to do something like this product page http://mackmarkcards.com/SCR-216.. So it is possible in magento.

Comment: @AditiPatel Do you use jQuery?

Comment: No Very littel idea About jQuery Just edit some code but not create a new one.

Comment: Ok, it's fine! I've made this. You need to access your ftp, go to the folder of the theme you are using (ex: /app/design/frontend/base/default/) and then go to /template/catalog/product/view/ and inside this folder is a file named **addtocart.phtml**, open this file and **replace all the code** for the code in this file: [link](https://goo.gl/ZaMgs9), save the file to your server and try it out.. Let me know!

Comment: @AditiPatel Did it work?

Comment: No its Not Working With my code...I m Using Porto Theme For My magento Project So its not changed.